# What are the chances to have three equal numbers on dice, three times in a row?

Tags: probability, dice

So, my friends and I were playing a game with dice, and we used to get three equal numbers three times in a row. So we are wondering, what are the probabilities for something like that to occur?

Comment: Do you mean three consecutive triples, or the same three consecutive triples?  Does $2-2-2,3-3-3,4-4-4$ count, or would you have to have $1-1-1$ three straight times?

Comment: We got 5-5-5, 6-6-6, 4-4-4. Like this.

Comment: ${1\over6^6}\approx .00002143347$

Answer (score 1):

For three dice to land on the same number, whatever the first die is, the second and third must have its value. The probability of this happening is $\frac16$ for the second die, times $\frac16$ for the third die.

Now, the probability of this event occurring thrice is simply the probability of it occurring once, cubed. This gives a final answer of $$\left(\frac16\times\frac16\right)^3=\frac1{6^6}\approx0.0021433\%.$$